# Solving USACO 1.1 – Friday the Thirteenth with date.h

Tags: c++, date

The [USACO 1.1 – Friday the Thirteenth](http://jackneus.com/programming-archives/friday-the-thirteenth/) problem has been solved many times in various ways.  Indeed it has generated a handful of questions on StackOverflow with various solutions:

- [Friday the Thirteenth - USACO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38037361/576911)
- [What is wrong with my code? Usaco: Friday the Thirteenth](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27924138/576911)
- [usaco: friday the thirteen error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11729685/576911)
- [Usaco. Friday the thirteen. What is wrong with my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21243273/576911)
- [On what days does the thirteenth occur? USACO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31231343/576911)

The question is:  What would a solution look like using a [modern C++11/14 date library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) such as the one I've linked to?

Would it be significantly simpler than the other solutions?  Easier to write?  More efficient?

Comment: Nice attempt for a canonical to bail out such crap questions early :-) ... (out of votes today, sorry)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem statement is to count the frequency with which the 13th of each month falls on a given weekday in the range `[1900-01-01, 2300-01-01)`.

Using [date.h](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/date.h) this is very easily and efficiently accomplished like this:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    unsigned freq[7] = {};
    for (auto ym = 1900_y/January; ym < 2300_y/January; ym += months{1})
        freq[weekday{ym/13}.c_encoding()]++;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
        std::cout << weekday{i} << " : " << freq[i] << '\n';
}
```

`ym` is a `date::year_month` object.  You can think of this as like a `time_point`, but it has a very coarse precision of `months`.

You simply loop over each year, and each month of each year, and compute the day of the week for the 13th of that month, and cast that `weekday` into an `unsigned`.

The high-level syntax is quite straight forward and readable.

The algorithms under the hood are [`days_from_civil`](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#days_from_civil) and [`weekday_from_days`](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#weekday_from_days).  Neither one of these low-level date algorithms are iterative, and thus they are very efficient.  So you get the best of both worlds:  Readable high-level syntax, and high performance.

The output of this simple program is also quite readable:

```
Sun : 687
Mon : 685
Tue : 685
Wed : 687
Thu : 684
Fri : 688
Sat : 684
```

It turns out Friday the 13th is slightly more likely than the other days of the week.

In C++17, you can even create a `constexpr std::array<unsigned, 7>` with these results (should it be important for some reason to have such numbers at compile-time):

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <array>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

constexpr
std::array<unsigned, 7>
compute_freq() noexcept
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    decltype(compute_freq()) freq = {};
    for (auto ym = 1900_y/January; ym < 2300_y/January; ym += months{1})
        freq[weekday{ym/13}.c_encoding()]++;
    return freq;
}

constexpr auto freq = compute_freq();

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    static_assert(freq[Sunday.c_encoding()]    == 687);
    static_assert(freq[Monday.c_encoding()]    == 685);
    static_assert(freq[Tuesday.c_encoding()]   == 685);
    static_assert(freq[Wednesday.c_encoding()] == 687);
    static_assert(freq[Thursday.c_encoding()]  == 684);
    static_assert(freq[Friday.c_encoding()]    == 688);
    static_assert(freq[Saturday.c_encoding()]  == 684);
}
```

which generates this assembly:

```
_freq:
    .long   687                     ## 0x2af
    .long   685                     ## 0x2ad
    .long   685                     ## 0x2ad
    .long   687                     ## 0x2af
    .long   684                     ## 0x2ac
    .long   688                     ## 0x2b0
    .long   684                     ## 0x2ac
```

And you just can't get more efficient than that.

In C++20 this all becomes available in your std::lib.  To port the above programs to C++20, drop `#include "date/date.h"` and `using namespace date;`.  Also change the `_y` suffix to `y`.